# how to connect the local host to the internet server on netbeans(java)?

Tags: database, netbeans, localhost

I have developed a netbeans project with a database connected using derby local server. when i distribute this project to other computer systems , how do i make the updates done on the table through other systems reflect on all other systems? DOes this involve connecting the host to the internet server?

Comment: published your application in local PC, share hosting then you can access in other PC also. IP will be Fix.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps? How to share hosting ?